'CLR/System.IO.IOException' при вызове метода Console.Clear(); в Visual Studio Code

в 'System.Console.dll' произошло необработанное исключение типа 'System.IO.IOException'.

Приложение (проект) какого типа? Судя по параметру throwOnNoConsole, отсутствует консоль.

@AlexanderPetrov Это консольное приложение по типу проекта. То есть как это отсутсвует консоль?

Хорошо, с типом приложения разобрались. Тогда показывайте код. Есть там где-то Console.SetOut?

@AlexanderPetrov Да нет. Как видно на изображении компилятор ругается именно на Console.Clear();

Покажите код! Да, компилятор может ругаться на вызов одного метода из-за другого метода. Повторяю вопрос: где-то в вашем коде переназначается вывод с помощью SetOut?

Нет, такой штуки в коде нет абсолютно нигде.

То есть код вы не покажете? Ладно, умываю руки.

А как мне его показать и где? Прям в комментариях?  Целиком или определенную часть?

@AlexanderPetrov Я понял! Вы хотите, чтобы я скинул вам свой GitHub, да?
